# Bunch of errors while using Flask command to make simple website

Tags: python, html, flask

so I've been following this tutorial on how to build an basic Flask website off youtube  [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIgPMguqyws&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-n4vJJybUVV3Un_NFS5EOgX&index=2). Currently trying to add HTML templates which are giving me "500 Internal Server Error" with application errors in the CMD.

**My python code
**`

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/<name>")
def home(name):
    return render_template("index.html", content=name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`**my html code  **`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ETF World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Explore the world of Exchange Traded Funds</h1>
        <p>{{content}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bradley J Stewart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Bradley J Stewart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Bradley J Stewart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Bradley J Stewart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
TypeError: home() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

I expected the website to work when I enter a forward slash in the URL and for dynamic information to pass information to be delivered from the backend to the front of what "content" variable I wrote. Not 100% sure if the video is relevant anymore as it is 3 years old

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

it happens to work on mine though.
main.py

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/<name>")
def home(name):
    return render_template("index.html", content=name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

index.html:

```
<head>
    <title>ETF World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Explore the world of Exchange Traded Funds</h1>
        <p>{{content}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

also make sure to put index.html to the template folder because flask look into that folder.

[image]